# How to create a comparator with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

*I'm new to Boost, but not to functional programming, and I'm trying to see where Boost can help me out.*

I have a list of 2D points, and I want to extract the minimum `x` coordinate. The `Point` class has a member function `float x() const` so I can use `boost::mem_fn` as follows:

```
boost::mem_fn(&Point::x)
```

But in order to use `std::min_element`, I need an object that supports `bool operator()(Point const &, Point const &)`. Something like this fictional `compare_by`:

```
leftmostPoint = std::min_element(
    points.begin(), points.end(),
    boost::compare_by(boost::mem_fn(&Point::x)));
```

Can I use Boost to construct such a comparison, or do I need to do this myself?

---

Update: Here's my own implementation, but I'm still interested to see how Boost could've done this for me.

```
template<typename F>
class CompareBy {
    F const d_f;
    public:
        CompareBy(F f) : d_f(f) { }
        template<typename T>
        bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const {
            return d_f(a) < d_f(b);
        }
};

template<typename F>
CompareBy<F> compare_by(F f) {
    return CompareBy<F>(f);
}
```

Usage: as above, minus the `boost::` namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any boost construct similar to your Compare_by.
However, boost::bind can do the trick.

```
Point leftmostPoint = *std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(),
   boost::bind(std::less<Point::type_x>(), 
       boost::bind( &Point::x, _1 ), boost::bind( &Point::x, _2 )));
```

Yeah, that's not pretty :/
Luckily, there is a syntax shortcut available, because function objects produced by boost::bind overload a lot of usual operator, like <, so you can do :

```
Point leftmostPoint2 = *std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(),
boost::bind( &Point::x, _1 ) < boost::bind( &Point::x, _2 ));
```

But I think only C++0X's lambda can really achieve brevity **and** clarity :

```
Point leftmostPoint3 = *std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(),
[](const Point& p1, const Point& p2){ return p1.x < p2.x; });
```

Comment: I think the lamba needs a boolean return type, i.e., `[](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) -> bool`.